# Full wave rectifier 2nd and 4th waves doesn't go up as it should

Tags: diodes, ac, oscilloscope, rectifier, waveform

I'm using four 1N4007 diodes and one 15k resistor. I already changed diodes and cables dozens of times, it doesn't change, even I change the oscilloscope or arbitrary function generator, nothing changes. What can be the problem? I'm using 5VAC at 50Hz.

When I tried the same circuit that I built on breadboard it worked yesterday, but now it doesn't work. It's the same circuit. I didn't even changed anything. How?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

Comment: I added another photo, I'm using a arbitrary function generator, Crocs of the function generator are attached to the jumper cables, blue and white one at the center of diodes

Comment: The first thing comes to my mind is that the probe GND and the signal generator GND might have somehow shorted. If they are plugged in the same earthed socket then this can happen because the scope GND is internally connected to the earth (PE), and the function generator's output GND might also be internally connected to the earth. Make sure they are not. This will turn your bridge rectifier into a half-wave rectifier.

Comment: I added a schematic, it's the same circuit as this one.

Comment: They aren't plugged in the same earthed socket, as I said, it's the same circuit, same oscilloscope and the same arbitrary function generator, it was working but now it doesn't, I didn't touched anything.

Comment: oscilloscope probes are connected to the load, not the generator. This is the waveform of the load.

Comment: Is the output from your function generator floating? If not, you are shorting the negative half-cycle via your oscilloscope probe ground clip.

Comment: @Hereforasking All of the outlets on your house are connected in parallel. So if your scope and your function generator both have ground pins on their cables, then the ground of your scope is connected to the ground of your generator. As a result, you're effectively shorting out the negative half cycle of your waveform.

Comment: How did you source the circuit when it worked? You need to have changed something, for example swap a AC supply with the function generator.

Comment: @Hereforasking "not plugged into the same earthed socket" but they are both plugged into earthed sockets? It doesn't have to be the *same* socket so long as they're both plugged into the same earth potential, and it's a pretty safe bet that any earthed socket in the same building has the same earth potential. You may need to isolate your signal generator for this measurement (for various reasons, isolating the scope is not a good idea).